# Overloading ostream << operator for a class with private key member

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading, ostream, member-access

I am trying to overload the ostream << operator for `class List`

```
class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
};
class List
{
private:
    Node *head;
public:
    List() : head(NULL) {}
    void insert(int d, int index){ ... }
 ...}
```

To my humble knowledge (overload ostream functions) must be written outside the class. So, I have done this:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, List L)
{
    Node *currNode = L.head;
    while (currNode != NULL)
    {
        out << currNode->data << " ";
        currNode = currNode->next;
    }
    return out;
}
```

But of course, this doesn't work because the member `Node head` is `private`.
What are the methods that can be done in this case other than turning `Node *head` to `public`?

Comment: Either use `friend` or provide a public `ostream& put(ostream & os)` member function in your class,. which can be used by the global operator overload.

Comment: You have to add the **friend declaration** `ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, List L);` inside the class.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have already tried using  `friend` declaration and it worked just fine. But I am interested in your method as well. Could you please elaborate more about it?

Comment: @7mood912 well, something like `std::ostream& Node::put(std::ostream& os) { Node *currNode = this;  while (currNode != NULL) {
        os << currNode->data << " ";
        currNode = currNode->next;
    }
    return os; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by adding a **friend declaration** for the overloaded `operator<<` inside class' definition as shown below:

```
class List
{
   //add friend declaration
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, List L);
   
   //other member here
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the function signature inside the class and mark it as `friend`, then define it outside the class if you want.